# How do I get ten millionths of a second in JavaScript? "fffffff"

Tags: javascript

I need a date format like this: `yyyy-MM-dd_HH.mm.ss.fffffff`

And I tried this:

```
var currentdate = new Date();
var fileName = currentdate.getFullYear() + '-'
   + currentdate.getMonth() + '-'
   + currentdate.getDate() + '_'
   + currentdate.getHours() + '.'
   + currentdate.getMinutes() + '.'
   + currentdate.getSeconds() + '.'
   + currentdate.getMilliseconds();
```

And output is this: `2014-3-2_23.0.29.840`

How can I get **ten millionths of a second** so my output will be something like following?

`2014-3-2_23.0.29.8401111`

For some reasons I can't use libraries such as moment.js.

Thanks.

Comment: javascript doesn't have that kind of accuracy, so you could just multiply milliseconds by 10000.

Comment: JavaScript's `Date` class doesn't have access to that kind of precision, so at best you're going to produce things like `2014-3-2_23.0.29.8400000`

Comment: In browsers that support it, you can use https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Performance.now() though i'm not sure how you would integrate that with Date.

Comment: My guess is that you need to write files with unique file names.  You're asking the wrong question.

Comment: @Brad, I'm working an a small task where I had to upload files to S3 from client browser. The requirement is keeping the patterns of old implementation which is server based file upload, in ASP.NET. Current server side pattern is `yyyy-MM-dd_HH.mm.ss.fffffff`, so I need to keep this in client.

Comment: @Zafar You might as well pick a random number for resolution below millisecond.

Comment: @Brad, that is an alternative solution which works perfectly. I was just wondering if this is possible with JS's native functions.

Comment: @Zafar If you want a specific number of digits, you're going to need to format the number as a string.

Comment: @Zafar, Actually, if you can assume that you work only with modern browsers, my answer should help you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Date](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/now) object doesn't manage accuracy beyond milliseconds, however, recently the browsers have begun to implement the method [performance.now()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Performance.now%28%29), that returns " *a DOMHighResTimeStamp, measured in milliseconds, accurate to one thousandth of a millisecond equal to the number of milliseconds since the `PerformanceTiming.navigationStart` property*"

There is an interesting post [here](http://dvolvr.davidwaterston.com/2012/06/24/javascript-accurate-timing-is-almost-here/) about that.

I've modified the `now()` function included in the post in order to work similar to `Date.now()` but with more precision: http://jsfiddle.net/aTpD5/3/

As summary, this is the code to achieve it:

```
var now = (function() {

  // Returns the number of milliseconds elapsed since either the browser navigationStart event or 
  // the UNIX epoch, depending on availability.
  // Where the browser supports 'performance' we use that as it is more accurate (microsoeconds
  // will be returned in the fractional part) and more reliable as it does not rely on the system time. 
  // Where 'performance' is not available, we will fall back to Date().getTime().

  var performance = window.performance || {};

  performance.now = (function() {
    return performance.now    ||
    performance.webkitNow     ||
    performance.msNow         ||
    performance.oNow          ||
    performance.mozNow        ||
    function() { return new Date().getTime(); };
  })();

  if (performance.timing) {
        return performance.timing.navigationStart + performance.now();
  }

  return performance.now();         

});
```

The now() function returns milliseconds with fractions of milliseconds, something like: "1396464605263.821ms" To format it you can use following code:

```
var exactNow = now();
$('#output').text(exactNow + 'ms')
var isostr = new Date(exactNow).toISOString().replace(/T/, " ");
// You can increase the precision changing the 6 by a higher number
var fractionms = ('' + (exactNow % 1)).substring(2, 6);
isostr = isostr.substring(0, isostr.length - 1) + fractionms;
$('#output2').text(isostr)
```

Previous code will show something like:

```
1396465845046.267ms
2014-04-02 19:10:45.0462670
```

This feature doesn't work on Safari, but It should work on other modern browsers:

- Chrome: 20+ (webkit)
- Firefox: 15.0+ (Gecko)
- Internet Explorer: 10.0+
- Opera: 15.0+
- Safari: Not supported (Tested on 7.0.3 in OSX)

Comment: Awesome. Here is the [browser support information](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Performance.now()) for those who interested more. Seems Safari & IE is loosing the battle for support of this method.

Comment: According to Mozilla MDN doc, It should work on IE 10+. But with Safari there is no luck.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there is no such function to retrieve the current nanosecond. Ideally you would write an additional line:

`+ currentDate.getNanoseconds() * 10;` ** NOTE: NOT ACTUAL CODE **

but there is no such thing. I would just pad the time with `0000` if absolutely required.